# get rid of some parts of png in java

Tags: java, image, png, jpanel

In my program,I am producing a png from a panel,but I want to get rid of the bounding box of 
this panel and to be more focused to the object in the panel.To do so, I want to get rid of the peripheral parts of png, and produce only the center of it.How can i do that ?

Comment: how are you generating the PNG?  Can't you just offset it in the x and y axis, and reduce the height and width by twice this offset?

Comment: I am using this piece of code,I succeded to produce the png but.Now, the parts that I dont include in myclip seems black.I want to get a png in the same size with the clip that i construct.how can it be possible ? 

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, 
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) ;
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics() ;
g2.clipRect((int)(unionOfAll.getX()),(int)(unionOfAll.getY())
      ,(int)(unionOfAll.getWidth()),(int)(unionOfAll.getHeight())) ;
drawPanel.paint(g2);
g2.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileRealName + ".png"));

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have your image loaded into a BufferedImage (which seems to be the case), this code will crop the image from (x,y) to (width,height).

```
image = image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

Then save as normal.